# Angular: stopImmediatePropagation() not working on keydown

Tags: angular, keyboard-events

I have an `directive` attached to a `input` field, both are listening to the `keydown` event and in some cases I would like to stop the event bubbeling up in the `directive`. Calling `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` does not really stop the propagation.

Example:

**directive**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[myDirective]' })
export class MyDirective {
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) 
  keydownHandler(event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // seems to be not working!!
   console.log('[my-directive.ts]: keydownHandler', event)
  }
}
```

**component with input field**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
    <input type="text" myDirective (keydown)="keydownHandler($event)">
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  keydownHandler(event) {
    console.log('[hello.component.ts]: keydownHandler', event)
  }
}
```

I do not understand why `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` should not work, any ideas? Is there another way to avoid that the `keydown` is triggered on the `component` with the `input` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular optimizes event handlers, if you have two or more handlers for the same event it will add only one listener and dispatch result to all components. It means that `stopImmediatePropagation` now depends on angular dispatching order. You can add logging or debug order of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9587

As a workaround you can add event listener directly on the element

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    // add listener as first to allow to stop next event listener execution
    elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', (event: Event) => {
      if (this.disabled) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
    });
  }
```