Angular HTML calling function in onclick gives ReferenceError but console.log working
I want to stop default behavior of ionic back button
console.log is working
<ion-back-button onclick="event.stopImmediatePropagation(); console.log('hello')" slot="start">

onBack function is not working gets ReferenceError
<ion-back-button onclick="event.stopImmediatePropagation(); onBack()" slot="start">

even though i have clearly define function in class component file

I have also tried this.onBack() but not working.
export class Component implements OnInit {
onBack() {
  console.log("here");
 }
}




In Angular, you need to use event binding syntax instead of onclick:
<ion-back-button
  (click)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation(); onBack()"
  slot="start"
>

JavaScript's onclick event doesn't have the reference to the component, that's why the reference error is thrown. console.log() doesn't need the reference to the component and works as a result.

I have already tried that it says Property 'event' does not exist on type 'component'.

@Neeraj it should be $event, then it will work

@NarenMurali Now event.stopImmediatePropagation not working

@Neeraj see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562261
